# How to implement parental control in Windows Store application?

Tags: c#, windows-store, parental-control

I'm porting educational game to Windows Store. Game downloads levels from web site. I don't think they are moderated, so it seems I must restrict age rating to 12+. However, most of the content is good, and I can ensure say 100 levels are suitable for any age. Then I could bundle that part of the content with my application.

However, I want 12+ users still have access to full set of the web site provided levels. How do I provide such parental control in C# Windows Store application? Are there any classes that provide age/parental control status, or maybe I just need to ask user for his age before accessing unmoderated web site data?

Applications targets Windows 8 (not yet 8.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality was introduced in Windows 8.1 via the [`ContentRestrictions` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.contentrestrictions.aspx), so unfortunately there is no built-in way to do this in Windows 8.

You could use the Live SDK to [get access to the user's age](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh826536.aspx), assuming they didn't lie in their profile (and assuming you can get that data for Child Accounts; I don't know if there are special rules for children).